# The status code returned from the server was 413

Tags: c#, asp.net, infragistics

Getting this error on pages using https when an event handler is called. e.g selecting a row of data.

The data is in Infragistics UltraWebGrid.

Please advise.

Comment: Do a Google search on "HTTP 413", or post an actual question. Don't waste people's time with nonsense.

Comment: Its almost as if he is putting spam on this site.

Comment: That's an awesome title, sound like a mystery novel title or something.

Comment: This is indeed `programmer spam`.

Answer (score 6):

Http 413 is "Request Entry Too Large".  How big is the data row that you're selecting?  Also, I'd look at tools like fiddler and firebug to see how big the client's http request is and see what you can do to possibly reduce the size of the information going back to the server.  Implementing Paging on your data grid (if you aren't already) may help with this if you have a lot of records that aren't paged.

Comment: @Ken Spam or not, I hadn't looked for any other http 413 questions on the site prior to answering so figured I'd at least put a starting answer. I don't see the point of sounding rude even on these anyways. Never know when someone may mistake such "don't waste people's time" comments for some form of elitist game forum.

Comment: 4+ years later, I Googled "The status code returned from the server was: 413", this is the third result on Google, and @JamesEggers your answer helped me, despite the question being terrible. Thanks!